# Absolute positioning with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I thought I understood the rules of CSS positioning until I bumped into the simple code below (also in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLnza0qL/)).

```css
#outer {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px red;
}
#inner {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px blue;
  /*position: absolute;
    left: 15px;*/
}
```

```html
<p id="outer">outer
  <p id="inner">inner</p>
</p>
```

What I don't get is this:

1. When you uncomment the first `position: absolute;` rule, why isn't the `outer` placed on top of the `inner` paragraph? The outer paragraph doesn't have any non-static parent, so it should be placed relative to the browser window, right?
2. Comment the first rule. When you uncomment the `position: absolute; left: 15px;` of the `inner` paragraph, why is the element pushed down a bit?

Comment: The problem is that one `<p>` (paragraph) cannot be inside another one, so the browser closes the first one when it sees the second one opening. It also doesn't make sense in English, what does a paragraph inside another look like? Try doing this with `<div>`s. Paragraphs are only for blocks of text, divs are for blocks (divisions) of content

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia, ok, but the questions still apply because even if you un-nest them, the result is the same.

Comment: That's right. Unfortunately from my phone I cannot check (1) since I'm unable to edit the jsfiddle. About (2), if the element with absolute position is not on (0,0) position, it will keep its relative origin within the window. I took advantage of this when creating a [tooltip tool](http://www.picnicss.com/plugins/tooltip/) ([source](https://github.com/picnicss/picnic/blob/master/plugins/tooltip/_plugin.scss)). So you should also specify the `top` and `left` to make sure it's on that position.

Comment: Sorry, I rectify last comment, I was going to take advantage of that until I discover that each browser treats this differently

Comment: When `position: absolute;` is applied the margins no longer collapse on top of each other, hence why the position changes. Have a look at the margins in dev tools with `position: absolute;` on and off as that should help you understand.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia you said "if the element with absolute position is not on (0,0) position, it will keep its relative origin within the window". Can you expand on that? I thought that when you absolutely positioned it was like you took the element to the top left corner and then applied the CSS styles :S

Answer (score 0):

outer isn't repositioned, or doesn't appear to be, because inner (and outer) have a default margin which keeps it from rising to the top which, I presume, is what you expected.

The same is true for your second question. inner has margin and line-height. Play with that by setting margin, padding and line-height to zero, or some other value to see what happens.

btw, your HTML is invalid. A `<p>` element cannot contain another `<p>` element.

Comment: I understand that both elements have a margin, I can see that, but why is there an extra space for `outer` and not for `inner` in the first case? It's like it can see that `inner` is there

Comment: Try adding a third `<p>` paragraph styled like `inner` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @l19 There isn't extra space. Outer will be positioned relative to the body while inner is positioned relative to outer.

Answer (score 0):

Full Discloser : That is not considered valid markup by the W3C HTML Validator so results may vary when working with non-valid markup. A good refactor (assuming you would want the `#inner` tag styled differently would be to wrap it in a `<span></span>` tag and style appropriately.

Now to answer Question 1 : My answer would be because once you give an element a `position: absolute:` rule with no parent that has a `position: relative;` rule, it will be positioned relative to the browser window and removed from the document flow. From there the `#inner` element will ignore the `#outer` element and take it's place in the document flow.

Question 2 : The spacing you are seeing is because of the default margins that are applied to a `<p></p>` tag. See attached screenshot for a reference[image]

Answer (score 0):

No block level elements are allowed inside the `p` tag.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Your original html the browser receives

`<p id="outer">outer
  <p id="inner">inner</p>
</p>`

It notices that it's invalid and corrects it. The browser add a closing `p` tag after the text **outer**. This leaves it with a closing `</p>` tag. It corrects this too by adding an opening `<p>` tag.

Here is the html created by the browser. The tags added by the browser are in bold

`<p id="outer"> outer`**`</p>`**
`<p id="inner"> inner </p>`
**`<p>`**`</p>`

And hence you are not getting the results that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a `<p>` element shouldn't contain another `<p>` element. Both `#inner` and `#outer` are `<p>` elements, they have a `display: block` by default. They also have a margin top and bottom.

1. When you set `#outer` with `position: absolute`, if you inspect you can see that `#outer` is position relative to its first positioned ancestor element - the `<body>`.
2. If you change your code to:

   ```
   <div id="outer">outer 
       <p id="inner">inner</p>
   </div>
   ```

   Then apply `position: absolute` and `left: 15px` to `#inner`it is now relative to its ancestor element - `#outer`.

If you need the `#inner` to flow on top of `#outer` then you need to change the display value to `display: inline;` to both elements and set `position: absolute` on the `#inner` and remove position value on the `#outer`.

Remember: `position: absolute` = The element is positioned **relative** to its **first** positioned (not static) **ancestor element**.

https://jsfiddle.net/f3sgvcd0/1/